# Resizing browser window leaves space on right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I came across this problem while making a sample having container element with inner elements. Those inner elements have float property set, but this makes the container border looks weird when browser window resized.

Even though the inner elements came one below another because of float property and min-width set, it dint effect the border of container element. It leaves a huge space on right. No clue why it is happening.

[image]

Following is what i have done:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
.container::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  min-width: 340px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-panel {
  border: 1px solid #F1FB3B;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-panel'>
    <div class='info'>
      <p style='font-weight:800;font-size:13px;line-height:2;'>Info:</p>
    </div>
    <div class='data'>
      <p style='font-weight:800;font-size:13px;line-height:2;'>Data:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right-panel'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/520/300' height='210' width='100%' style='vertical-align:top;' />
  </div>
```

Comment: well thats because its floating :S

Comment: fix it by setting a width for the container or use a table

Comment: @CodeiSir Well in case of setting width of container, its not helping in making the page responsive.

Comment: OR table (or css table or flex) ... also there was not word of responsiveness in your question

Comment: @CodeiSir Sorry that i dint mentioned in above question, but i would like to know the work around for above situation keeping responsiveness in mind. Is table should be approach i should proceed with?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the magic `display: table-cell;` ✨

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
.container::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 340px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-panel {
  border: 1px solid #F1FB3B;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left-panel'>
    <div class='info'>
      <p style='font-weight:800;font-size:13px;line-height:2;'>Info:</p>
    </div>
    <div class='data'>
      <p style='font-weight:800;font-size:13px;line-height:2;'>Data:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right-panel'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/520/300' height='210' width='100%' style='vertical-align:top;' />
  </div>
```

Comment: Dont know which browser you tested, but doesnt work for me on chrome browser. I am using `display:table-cell` css for my left & right panel, but the effect is same as earlier one. i.e. one with the spacing problem